# Regular expression failure in javascript usage

Tags: javascript, regex, date-parsing

I can't get a regex to match anything in my javascript function and I've run out of ideas for what's wrong. I've been working on this snippet for better part 1/2 day searching and trying other people's regex strings and every attempt fails with m=null. It's got to be something simple ... I'm not able to see it.

The regex string I've settled on is validated here: [Sample](https://rubular.com/r/HXrG3dPNw7YXRv)

The goal of the js function is to make the input time be output in 24hr time. The alerts are only for testing.

**Here's my javascript code:**

```
//
// Enable a prototype getHours function
//
Date.prototype.addHours= function(h){
   this.setHours(this.getHours()+h);
    return this;
}
        
//
// Input:  string '07/19/2020 08:40 PM'
// Output: date   07/19/2020 20:40
//
function strToDate(dateString){
    try {   
        var dateobject;
        var dateReg = /^(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4}) (\d{1,2}):(\d{1,2}):(\d{1,2}) ([AP]M)$/;
        var m = dateString.match(dateReg);
        if (m) {
            dateobject = new Date(m[1], m[2]-1, m[3], m[4], m[5], 0)
            if (m[6] == 'PM') {
                dateobject = dateobject.addHours(12)
            }
        } else { 
            alert('no match');             
        }
        return dateObject;
    } catch (ex) {
        alert('error: ' + ex);
    }
}
```

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `07/19/2020 08:40 PM` does not contain seconds. Are seconds optional? Try `/^(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4}) (\d{1,2}):(\d{1,2})(?::(\d{1,2}))? ([AP]M)$/`, see https://regex101.com/r/63Attp/1

Comment: Your regular expression is expression is expected to match seconds too, but your documentations shows it doesn't return seconds, that may be the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing line:

```js
var dateReg = /^(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4}) (\d{1,2}):(\d{1,2}):(\d{1,2}) ([AP]M)$/;
```

to:

```js
var dateReg = /^(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4}) (\d{1,2}):(\d{1,2}) ([AP]M)$/;
```

There are two colons (`:`) in your regex, but only one colon in the time.

Also there's a missing space between the time part and AM/PM part.

I verified it here: https://regex101.com/r/szity1/1

Answer (score 0):

Your code fixed below, the mistakes were:

- Wrong pattern in the regexp as you don't pass seconds
- Wrong case on `dateObject` variable name
- Wrong parameters order in [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date) constructor

```js
//
// Enable a prototype getHours function
//
Date.prototype.addHours= function(h){
   this.setHours(this.getHours()+h);
    return this;
}
        
//
// Input:  string '07/19/2020 08:40 PM'
// Output: date   07/19/2020 20:40
//
function strToDate(dateString){
    try {   
        var dateObject;
        var dateReg = /^(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4}) (\d{1,2}):(\d{1,2}) ([AP]M)$/;
        var m = dateString.match(dateReg);
        if (m) {
            dateObject = new Date(m[3], m[1]-1, m[2], m[4], m[5], 0)
            if (m[6] == 'PM') {
                dateObject = dateObject.addHours(12)
            }
        } else { 
            alert('no match');             
        }
        return dateObject;
    } catch (ex) {
        alert('error: ' + ex);
    }
}

console.log(strToDate('07/19/2020 08:40 PM').toLocaleString());
```